# Trying to figure out how to use jQuery index() buried in parent elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the index of a group of elements (in this example, the a tags with the class myLink).  They are nested within parent elements. All my efforts thus far produce a 0 index for the first item, but a -1 index for the second. An example of the structure I'm looking at is:

```js
// GeekInTheBox - please fill this out
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="containerOne">
  <ul class="listOne">
    <li>
      <a class="myLink" href="blah">Link Text</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="myLink" href="moreBlah">More Link Text</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script>
    $('.myLink').on('click', function(){
        alert($(this).index($('.myLink')));
        alert($(this).index($('.containerOne .listOne a')));
        alert($(this).index($('.containerOne .listOne li a')));
        alert($(this).index($('.containerOne .listOne .myLink')));
        alert($(this).index($('.containerOne .listOne li .myLink')));
        alert($(this).index($('.containerOne .listOne a.myLink')));
        alert($(this).index($('.containerOne .listOne li a.myLink')));
        alert($(this).index());
        return false;
    })
</script>
```

Comment: _"All my efforts thus far produce a 0 index for the first item"_ Can you include `javascript` that you have tried at Question? How is `.index()` called?

Comment: Please click the `<>` snippet editor and give us a [mcve]

Comment: ^ edit your question with that, not as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `.index()` on a collection of items (such as `$('.myLink')`), and pass `this` as an argument - then you'll get the index of `this` within the collection

```js
// GeekInTheBox - please fill this out
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="containerOne">
  <ul class="listOne">
    <li>
      <a class="myLink" href="blah">Link Text</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="myLink" href="moreBlah">More Link Text</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script>
    $('.myLink').on('click', function(){
        alert($('.myLink').index(this));
        return false;
    })
</script>
```

Comment: can use just `this` without wrapping in `$()` ... `$('.myLink').index(this)`

Comment: works perfectly. THANK YOU. I've been smashing my head into the keyboard for two hours trying to figure this out on my own.